# Java: Узнать количество строк, полученных в запросе

Tags: jdbc, java, select, mysql

В общем работаю с MySQL через JDBC. Делаю запрос в базу:

```
SELECT * FROM Leters LIMIT 0, 500
```

На выходе получаю естественно объект ResulSet, но как узнать сколько строк вернул запрос. Методы getFetchSize() и getFetchDirection() возвращают не то. Может быть как-то через другие объекты это делается?

Answer (score 3):

Придумал еще 2 способа

1. `ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table");`  
   `resultSet.last();` 
   `int rowCount = resultSet.getRow();`
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`

Comment: Ну первый способ это упрощенная версия моего способа))) Однострочник так сказать. Второй способ я пробовал, не вышло. Выдает ошибку "Before open ResultSet", хотя вроде все по-уму.

Comment: я еще думал вариант, обычного i++ в цикле. а со 2м не должно быть проблем, это же обычный запрос, который вернет кол-во строк

Answer (score 2):

Хм. Предусмотренного метода "из коробки" как я понимаю нет. Придется делать что-то вроде:

```
public static int getResultSetRowCount(ResultSet resultSet) {
int size = 0;
try {
    resultSet.last();
    size = resultSet.getRow();
    resultSet.beforeFirst();
}
catch(SQLException ex) {
    return 0;
}
return size;
}
```

Печально :(

Answer (score 1):

```
while (rs.next()){
    i++;
}
```

Comment: ну это самое простое  решение))) это занимает лишнее время, а это недопустимо))

Comment: не думаю, что оно особо отличается от предыдущих, можно, в некоторых случаях оно лучше, например, когда тебе этот результат надо "не сразу", а обходить ResultSet ты все равно будешь, можно заодно и размер собрать =)

Comment: в том-то и дело, что он мне нужен сразу :) эх, ладно, наваю сам метод... Вообще меня поражает отсутствие иногда элементарных методов казалось бы)))

Comment: А как Вы представляете себе физическую реализацию того, что Вы хотите ?

СУБД исполняет SQL запрос и в общем случае **не знает** размер результата. Получаемые в ходе исполнения данные сразу отправляются клиенту.

"Благодарите" создателей SQL, не предусмотревшим (видимо сознательно) управление физическими аспектами функционирования СУБД на уровне SQL запросов.

Comment: ну не знаю, ResulSet - объект? уже него же есть определенный размер?

Comment: @Gorets, вот для примера у ArrayList<String> какой размер ? 

Он меняется в зависимости от того, что Вы туда напихаете.

Comment: ну после того как я напихаю туда что-то, я могу узнать размер? вот почему же тогда с ResulSet после получение результата, я не могу получить size?

Comment: Потому что до прочтения всего (.next()) это будет не **действительный** size, а size на данный  момент ( в общем источник логических ошибок).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет DatabaseMetaData (см. JavaDoc).

Comment: хотя мне больше нравится ответ @Chupa

Comment: Это информация по столбцам.